# Is it possible to use Ash window manager from Chrome OS?

Tags: software-installation, gui, window-manager

Is it possible to use Ash window manager from Chrome OS?

Here is how it looks like:

[image: Chrome OS]
[image: Chrome OS]

[More info](https://www.chromestory.com/2012/04/aura-and-ash-in-chrome-os-what-are-they/)

Comment: Have you seen This: [How to run ChromeOS in Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/11/how-to-run-chromeos-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to run the Aura window manager with Ubuntu thanks, to github user dz0ny.

To install Aura run:

```
wget https://github.com/downloads/dz0ny/lightdm-login-chromeos/lightdm-login-chromiumos_1.0_amd64.deb
```

Then:

```
sudo dpkg -i lightdm-login-chromiumos_1.0_amd64.deb
```

You can run it standalone mode from the login screen or in windowed mode within Ubuntu using `chromeos`.

Note:  This only works in the 64 bit (ARM64) version of Ubuntu.

#### IMPORTANT: Not everything works correctly.  For more information: [ChromeOS Ubuntu -Github](https://github.com/dz0ny/lightdm-login-chromeos)

[image]

Comment: I am getting an error every time i try to install it like    `nzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /tmp/fileR2uWh2.zip or
        /tmp/fileR2uWh2.zip.zip, and cannot find /tmp/fileR2uWh2.zip.ZIP, period`

Answer (score 2):

You are able to get the ChromeOS desktop in it's own window via the chrome unstable branch.

google-chrome-unstable -open-ash

Comment: Nice! To get the unstable Chrome, click on the "deb package" [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/google_chrome/stable/main/base/google-chrome-unstable)