# Style windows like Aura window manager from Chromium OS

Tags: 13.10, themes, chromium

How can I style my desktop windows to be like [Aura window manager](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/aura) on my Ubuntu machine without installing Chromium OS or [alternative](https://github.com/dz0ny/lightdm-login-chromeos)?

[image]

Is there any already built theme for Ubuntu?

Note that I only want to apply the window border style. I don't want for example the bottom launcher.

Comment: Have you seen this Q/A? http://askubuntu.com/questions/190362/is-it-possible-to-use-ash-window-manager-from-chrome-os/220598#220598

Comment: @Seth I haven't, but the solution is installing the package from github. I dont want to install that (I've already tested it). I only want to apply the border style to the windows from the desktop. That's the question...

Comment: Yes, I just saw that. Sorry for not reading ever link before commenting ;P  Looks like you'd be looking for Chromium theme more than anything else.

Comment: @Seth Not a problem, maybe you find a good solution.. :-)

Comment: You may wish to re-word the question in order to include what you mention in your comments as the main question. One thing is "how to install window manager" and a different thing is what you wish "to apply the border style to the windows from the desktop". There are good chances to get a good answer for theming your desktop windows without installing a window manager itself. Thank you.

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo Yes, that's true. Edited it. If you want to edit it to be clearer, I would be thankful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desktop Window Decorations can be managed by the window decoration engine itself. In this case I will suggest the usage of Emerald Window Decorator. You may need to also install Compiz Config Settings Manager in order to obtain a better results.

To install Emerald simply drop the next in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install emerald
```

Provide your user password and wait for Emerald to finish installing. After which you will need to run `emerald --replace` in order to allow Emerald to take control on the window decoration. The basic decoration (red in my case) may look ugly, but you can find fancy Emerald themes by simply running a search on the net using your favorite search engine, [**this page**](http://linux-lounge.deviantart.com/gallery/28339069) -in example- contains cool windows decorations based on Emerald.

[image]

The **[Radiance_Suite by nale12](http://nale12.deviantart.com/art/Radiance-suite-284675661)** looks much like the effect you're after. But playing with the settings in the "Edit Themes" tab of the Emerald Themer you can create your own customized theme starting from an existing one.

[image]

In combination with a Chrome's Aero theme you may get the full effect you're looking for in Chrome, but Aero themes will require gtk2 so you may find a major problem to make Chrome's Aero themes transparent.

[image]

During the process to get exactly what you wish you may find an issue or two, but it will be funny and illustrative, believe me.

Good luck!

Comment: That package doesn't exist..

Comment: Edited to include repository.

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo Interesting tool, can I export the theme somehow and autoload it without emerald? I would like to replace the theme files on the hard drive and to remove this program.

Comment: I don't think so. Each window decorator manages its own decoration engine so it may represent a major issue trying to export from emerald to a different window manager. Anyway, there are good tools for theming your Ubuntu based on your current window manager. Just let us know which one you wish to use and let's see how far can we get theming. In a different question, please, and don't forget to drop back a link to follow up.