# Ubuntu - Chrome OS look

Tags: themes, google-chrome

Is it possible to somehow apply the look of chrome os on ubuntu? I need exactly the same look :D

Comment: Open Chrome and run it full screen? ChromeOS is just a web browser, after all.

Comment: I know, but i just want the look of chrome os:S I want to use ubuntu, but with chrome os "theme"

Comment: Is [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/190362/is-it-possible-to-use-ash-window-manager-from-chrome-os/220598#220598) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you may want can be achieved with openbox desktop environment plus tint2 panel, both of which you can get with `sudo apt-get install openbox tint2 obmenu obconf feh` . Bellow is the screenshot of my desktop with the appropriate configuration for both. In order to have fn key work, make sure you autostart `gnome-settings-daemon` in the openbox autostart file. Autostart entries and panel launchers are done with .desktop files, about which you can learn [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles). Bellow is my configuration

[image]

**/home/username/.config/tint2/tint2rc file**

```
# Tint2 config file
# Generated by tintwizard (http://code.google.com/p/tintwizard/)
# For information on manually configuring tint2 see http://code.google.com/p/tint2/wiki/Configure

# Background definitions
# ID 1
rounded = 7
border_width = 2
background_color = #000000 60
border_color = #FFFFFF 16

# ID 2
rounded = 5
border_width = 0
background_color = #FFFFFF 40
border_color = #FFFFFF 48

# ID 3
rounded = 5
border_width = 0
background_color = #FFFFFF 16
border_color = #FFFFFF 68

# Panel
panel_items = LTSBC
panel_monitor = all
panel_position = bottom center horizontal
panel_size = 100% 35
panel_margin = 0 0
panel_padding = 7 0 7
panel_dock = 0
panel_dock = 0
wm_menu = 1
panel_layer = bottom
panel_background_id = 1

# Panel Autohide
autohide = 0
autohide_show_timeout = 0.3
autohide_hide_timeout = 2
autohide_height = 2
strut_policy = follow_size

# Taskbar
taskbar_mode = single_desktop
taskbar_padding = 2 3 2
taskbar_background_id = 0
taskbar_active_background_id = 0

# Tasks
urgent_nb_of_blink = 8
task_icon = 1
task_text = 0
task_centered = 1
task_maximum_size = 140 35
task_padding = 6 2
task_background_id = 3
task_active_background_id = 2
task_urgent_background_id = 2
task_iconified_background_id = 3
task_tooltip = 0

# Task Icons
task_icon_asb = 70 0 0
task_active_icon_asb = 100 0 0
task_urgent_icon_asb = 100 0 0
task_iconified_icon_asb = 70 0 0

# Fonts
task_font = sans 7
task_font_color = #FFFFFF 68
task_active_font_color = #FFFFFF 83
task_urgent_font_color = #FFFFFF 83
task_iconified_font_color = #FFFFFF 68
font_shadow = 0

# System Tray
systray = 1
systray_padding = 4 2 3
systray_sort = ascending
systray_background_id = 0
systray_icon_size = 35
systray_icon_asb = 70 0 0

# Clock
time1_format = %H:%M
time1_font = sans 8
time2_format = %A %d %B
time2_font = sans 6
clock_font_color = #FFFFFF 74
clock_padding = 1 0
clock_background_id = 0
clock_rclick_command = orage

# Tooltips
tooltip_padding = 2 2
tooltip_show_timeout = 0.7
tooltip_hide_timeout = 0.3
tooltip_background_id = 1
tooltip_font = sans 10
tooltip_font_color = #000000 80

# Mouse
mouse_middle = none
mouse_right = close
mouse_scroll_up = toggle
mouse_scroll_down = iconify

# Battery
battery = 1
battery_low_status = 10
battery_low_cmd = notify-send "battery low"
battery_hide = 98
bat1_font = sans 8
bat2_font = sans 6
battery_font_color = #FFFFFF 74
battery_padding = 1 0
battery_background_id = 0



# Launchers
#   
launcher_padding = 5 0 10
launcher_background_id = 9
launcher_icon_size = 45
launcher_item_app = /home/user/.config/autostart/chromium-browser.desktop
# launcher_item_app = /some/where/anotherapplication.desktop
launcher_item_app =  /home/user/.config/autostart/gnome-terminal.desktop
launcher_item_app = /usr/share/applications/gnome-alsamixer.desktop
# End of config
```

**/home/username/.config/openbox/autostart file**

```
# set background , use your own path to picture
feh --bg-fill /path/to/image &

# start tint2 panel
tint2 &

# start sound indicator thingy
gnome-sound-applet &

# start gnome-settings-daemon
gnome-settings-daemon &
```