# Best Ubuntu Version for my chromebook (closed)

Tags: unity, chromebook, distro-recommendation, chromeos, crouton

Im new to the ubuntu community and have hit a wall.

Im running an Asus c300 chromebook and have been playing with it for awhile.

Ive run KDE, Xfce, and unity. I like unity best as its easier to transition from the regular OS systems (windows/mac).

Problem is after using the crouton installer (which i still dont know the best crouton (ive only used trusty)) the distro seems to be missing much of what comes basic when installing on windows or mac.

SO the question is, What distro/crouton mix is best for my system and my experience?

Thanks,
PapaKei

Edit:Sarg answered the question perfectly. please see his comment if youre here looking for answers

Comment: What you're asking is a question that is a matter of opinion and will be closed soon. Have you carefully read the help center/tour post before asking this ? As for your question itself, here's my opinion on the matter: if you have chromebook with sufficient amount of RAM ( 4 GB ) and disk space - use Unity. Otherwise, use something else. It's a general approach to any laptop/netbook/chromebook

Comment: thank you. that makes the decision easier (opinions are what i was looking for as i have no experience with any distro)

Comment: I understand  you were looking for the opinions. It's just that this site isn't a forum and it's basically the rules to avoid questions that ask for opinions.  There's a new service , http://discourse.ubuntu.com/ , so your question probably will be more welcome there. On a side note, good luck with the chromebook ! Also, if you're into minimalism and not afraid of tweaking the desktop , give openbox a go. It's just barebone desktop, which you can customize with a few external apps.  See my post about it http://askubuntu.com/a/600496/295286

Comment: Thanks. ill go check out discourse. The openbox is exactly what i was looking for desktop wise. super helpfull. if you have any other recommendations please shoot me an email in your spare time 
Reversedlogic334@gmail.com

Comment: discourse is dead & shortly buried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity has the best software pack probably. So if it runs fine stick with that. Though Linux Mint may be better(not technically Canonical). Linux Mint is probably faster and more Windows like.

Comment: Ill give mint a shot. Is there a preferred crouton or will any do?

Comment: Too be honest I have never tried it. I would look for a reputable news site. I personally would go with lifehacker's sugesstion, but I don't own a chromebook.